# Issues with Downloading Macaulay 2

Tags: installation, cygwin, macaulay2

I am new to Macaulay 2 and running into trouble in attempting to download it.

Apparently since I am running Windows 7, I need to download a program called "Cygwin" in order to install M2 on my computer. I downloaded Cywgin and am currently attempting to figure out my issue with the instructions in the second to last paragraph here [image]

I am asked to choose 2 "mirror sites" one of which is the Macaulay site I was asked to enter in, and then I am asked to choose a site which is "geographically close to me." I have tried choosing all of the ".com" mirror sites but in doing so I receive the following error message:[image]

I attempted a random website to see whether the same error message would appear and it did. What am I missing here and is there an obvious mirror site I should be choosing?

Comment: Wrong website. It is not a programming question.

Comment: Have you also noted that "http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/Downloads/Microsoft-Windows/index.html" basically says that that they are not supporting this solution anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

Building M2 under Cygwin currently fails, it's an open issue on GitHub. So if you want to install Macaulay2, it's best to install VMware or VirtualBox software and virtually install ubuntu Or another GNU / Linux distribution and try [this link](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Downloads/GNU-Linux/index.html). In any case, if it is difficult to install Macaulay2 for you, you can use Macaulay2 online  https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/TryItOut/.